# My image is not getting uploaded in my html website , atom code editor app is used ,

Tags: image, upload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaxRI.jpg)

My code is completely fine , i even checked my file location and everything but still my image is not getting uploade in my website , i am using atom and its an html only file , a screenshot

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped, you need src and not scr, atom even marks it as weird.